# Nestjs won't start after upgrade to 7

Tags: nestjs

I upgraded my Nest app from 6 -> 7 today. After resolving all the typescript errors, I'm getting strange behavior on boot.

```
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] GraphqlClientModule dependencies initialized +138ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] SentryModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] HttpModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] DiscoveryModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] ConsoleModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] BullModule dependencies initialized +12ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] ScheduleModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] StorageModule dependencies initialized +7ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] KeyValueModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] IntercomModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] SentryCoreModule dependencies initialized +88ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] BullModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] GraphQLSchemaBuilderModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] PostmarkModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 15484   - 05/01/2020, 3:33:29 PM   [InstanceLoader] GraphQLModule dependencies initialized +1ms
```

And then it just stops. No additional output. There are many more modules.

Here are the relevant packages

```
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.1.4",
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.0.9",
    "@nestjs/config": "^0.4.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.9",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^7.3.5",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.9",
    "@nestjs/schedule": "^0.3.1",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.0.0",
```

For reference, here's my `main.ts`

```
import { NestFactory } from "@nestjs/core";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
import {
  initializeTransactionalContext,
  patchTypeORMRepositoryWithBaseRepository
} from "typeorm-transactional-cls-hooked";
import { ValidationPipe } from "@nestjs/common";
import helmet from "helmet";

initializeTransactionalContext();
patchTypeORMRepositoryWithBaseRepository();
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { bodyParser: false });
  app.enableCors();
  app.use(helmet());
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Update:

In my app module, I've tried commenting out all the application modules, and the app doesn't boot. I've tried commenting out *all* modules, and the app boots!

When I add in *just* `TypeOrmModule.forRoot()`, the app hangs and does not boot.

Comment: Does it just hang or does the process quit? Can you show your `main.ts`?

Comment: Just hangs, let me edit and post main.ts

Comment: Posted @JayMcDoniel! Also I've tried commenting out all my application modules, and just using library ones, and I'm getting the same behavior

Comment: Hmm deps and code looks fine so far. Any chance you can share code? Or a minimum reporduction?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, I'll try to make a reproduction. For now take a look at my update. I think it might have to do with @nestjs/typeorm

Comment: That would make it seem like there is a connectivity issue with the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a somewhat unsatisfying answer. When I upgraded the Nest packages, I forgot to mention that one of nest's dependencies said I didn't have a high enough version of Node. I was on 13.x, but it wanted something above 13.6, I believe.

I figured "I'll just go to the latest" and went to 14.x

This issue resolved when I went to node 13.14.0

Comment: It's possible this will help others in this situation: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5045 Nest should work with latest Node version

Comment: Confirmed, I can use node 14 with Nest, as long as pg is upgraded to ^8.3.0 not ^8.0.0 as quoted in the git issue above: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5045 Weirdest thing, but it works!

Comment: In my case I had to update my pg npm and it suddenly works, this ORM is the most infuriating thing i have ever used, with so many different ways to fail silently and break your code between patch updates

Answer (score -2):

Review the version of node in your docker.

Comment: Nothing is mentioned about the docker, and correct answer is already provided by author.